# Can't idenify where Subscript out of range error is originating

Tags: excel, vba, select, range

Whenever trying to select a variable range using a subroutine with parameters, I will also receive the error 9 Subscript out of range. If I remove the "ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")" I then receive a Gobal error.

I have tried using different routines such as Cells(x,y)

```
Sub Trail()

    Call SelectRow(2)

End Sub

Sub SelectRow(i As String)

    Dim theAddressA As String
    Dim theAddressL As String
    theAddressA = "A" & i
    theAddressL = "L" & i
    MsgBox (theAddressA) 'Prints "A2".
    MsgBox (theAddressL) 'Prints "L2".    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("theAddressA:theAddressL").Select

End Sub
```

I want to be able to select a row based on a variable input, as shown by the subroutine with the argument parameters. Ultimately once I can do this I'd like to compare individual rows with another table to then identify differences and similarities.
[Debug display image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9VS3.png)

Comment: Normally you don't need to `Select`, and probably should avoid it. See [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for more detail.

Comment: Do you have a sheet named "Sheet1" in your workbook? Also - a sheet must be active before you can select cell(s) on it - but as mentioned, you probably don't need to `Select` at all.

Comment: It is specifically called "Affected APAC Truck Pop", I though the sheets name would be Sheet1 as shown in the properties and the name I assigned in the excel workbook would not be reference. However, changing it to the name I assigned resolved my issue. Thanks Ben, I will also look at the link to avoid using Select. Many Thanks.

Comment: That is the codename. It is different from the actual sheet name. To use it, you would do `Sheet1.Range(theAddressA & ":" & theAddressL).Select`. But no problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont put your variables in quotes... they are not literal strings. Instead, concatenate them like this.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(theAddressA & ":" & theAddressL).Select
```

Comment: Thanks braX. However, I have tried this however, I am still getting the same "9" Subscript Error.

Comment: What does `MsgBox theAddressA & ":" & theAddressL` give you? Is there a sheet called "Sheet1" or is it called "Sheet 1"?

Comment: 'code' MsgBox theAddressA & ":" & theAddressL gives "A2:L2". the sheet is called Sheet1, more specifically "Affected APAC Truck Pop", changing it from Sheet1 to this resolved my issue! Thanks braX!

Answer (score 0):

I was referencing the name of the worksheet incorrectly, I thought that the name Sheet1 shown in the image would be what VBA references. However, it is the actual name which has been assigned that should be referenced. Thanks everyone

[Name should be referenced not (Name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/180Ge.png)

Comment: If you wanted to address the worksheet by index, you would do it like this: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`

Comment: `(Name)` is the name of VBA object and can be changed only in VBA editor. `Name` is the label displayed on sheet's tab. Instead of `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Affected APAC Truck Pop").Range(...` you can use `Sheet1.Range(...`.